# Event on marker click?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, laravel, marker

I use ivory-google-map to put multiple marker on google map.

```
foreach ($points as $point):
    $marker = new Marker();
    $marker->setPosition($point->lat, $point->lng);
    $marker->setInfoWindow($infoWindow);
    $this->map->addMarker($marker);
endforeach;
```

How add event for set center map marker what was clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of Ivory Google Maps:

https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-google-map/blob/master/doc/usage/events.md

Add an 'click' event on the marker, set the $handle as a function to set the map center:

```
$map->setCenter(YOUR-MARKER-LATITUDE, YOUR-MARKER-LONGITUDE, true);
```